# Macports compile of MySQL++ failing

Tags: mysql, macos, macports, mysql++

Before running "sudo port install mysqlxx +universal", I installed the universal variant of mysql5.

...
checking whether -lm is needed to use C math functions... no

checking whether -lsocket is needed... no

checking whether -lnsl is needed... no

checking for MySQL library directory... /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql

checking for MySQL include directory... /opt/local/include/mysql5/mysql

checking if we can link to MySQL C API library directly... no

checking zlib.h usability... yes

checking zlib.h presence... yes

checking for zlib.h... yes

checking for gzread in -lz... yes

checking whether adding -lz will let MySQL C API link succeed... no

configure: error: Unable to link to MySQL client library!

Comment: should be on serverfault

Comment: Should be reported to the maintainer of that port.  Meanwhile, since you're willing to compile from source, why not just download the tarball from http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/ and build it according to the included instructions?

Comment: @Warren Young: why don't you move your comment to the answer section .. it's the answer I'd have appreciated if this was my question?

Comment: Nah, doesn't really answer the question asked.  It's the right answer, but to a different question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what's going on here is that you're running Snow Leopard.  In previous versions of OS X, the default C++ compiler built 32-bit executables by default, but this changed to 64-bit in Snow Leopard.  This can cause link problems with the MySQL C API library if it's not built as a Universal library supporting both 64- and 32-bit executables.

There are a bunch of ways around this problem, but most of the ones I know about either won't work with MacPorts or I don't know how to make them work.  I've added a section on this to the MySQL++ README for Mac OS X, which you can read online, [here](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/mysqlpp/trunk/README-Mac-OS-X.txt?view=markup).

Perhaps you can figure out how to adapt these solutions to the MacPorts build system.  Something like this might work:

```
CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 sudo port install mysqlxx +universal
```

That depends on those environment variables making it through the `sudo` and `port` barriers.  You might have to get trickier.  For instance:

```
sudo -s
CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 port install mysqlxx +universal
```

As I commented above, it might be simplest to just build from the source tarball.